# Handle touch event for items inside Recyclerview - android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch-event, android-switch

i'm building a simple recyclerview with custom layout (Text view and switch) and a custom adapter.

My problem is i can't handle the click event for the switch (Which make it toggle its state), i have built a touch listener for the `RecyclerView` and it fires every time i click on the `Switch`.

After a lot of trials the switch touch listener fires also, but i want to disable the event of touch for the recyclerView if the switch is clicked.

**Here is my Layout code :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60.0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/category_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Category Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/category_switch"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checked="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**this is my adapter code :**

```
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_category, parent, false);
    CategoryViewHolder holder = new CategoryViewHolder(row);

    return holder;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    AlarmCategory thisCat = categories.get(position);

    holder.catName.setText(thisCat.getCategoryName());

    holder.catStatus.setChecked(thisCat.isOn());

    holder.catStatus.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("fpp", view.getClass().getName() + " is clicked");
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    public TextView catName;
    public SwitchCompat catStatus;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

        catName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        catStatus = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_switch);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, 1001, 0, "Edit");//groupId, itemId, order, title
        menu.add(0, 1002, 1, "Delete");
    }
}
```

**And here's my recyclerView touch handler :**

```
class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {

        this.clickListener = clickListener;

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));

            Log.d("fpp", child.getClass().getName() + " is clicked");

            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

**and in the `onCreate` Method i call it through :**

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent i = new Intent(CategoriesList.this, AlarmList.class);
            i.putExtra("catID", categories.get(position).getCategoryID());
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            catPos = position;
        }
    }));
```

Any help please, I already tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked for sorry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to update your holder to handle any view clicks internally, e.g.

```
public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnSetCheckedListener {
    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        catName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        catStatus = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_switch);
        catStatus.setOnCheckChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // deal with catStatus change
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // deal with itemView click
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, i wrote this code and added `Log.d("fopp", view.getClass().getName() + " is clicked from inner");` but nothing happened for sorry

Comment: You are using a gesture detector which steals the touch event and it won't be propagated for anything else. The code in the answer works, but for that you need to remove 1) `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener()` part and 2) the gesture detector

Comment: and how to handle the touch event on the layout itself ? i want to navigate to another activity when anything except the switch is clicked.

Comment: The `onClick(View view)` is the one for clicking the layout, i.e. `itemView`. `itemView` is your inflated layout view presentation. Just move your code for activity navigation into that method.

Answer (score 8):

1. Create class **RecyclerTouchListener**

   ```
   public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
   private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
   private ClickListener clickListener;

   public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
       this.clickListener = clickListener;
       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
               View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
               if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                   clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
               }
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
       View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
       if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
           clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
       }
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

   }

   public interface ClickListener {
       void onClick(View view, int position);

       void onLongClick(View view, int position);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use this Listener in Activity

   ```
   recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerview, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view, int position) {

              // Write your code here

           }

           @Override
           public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

           }
       }));
   ```